# C++ Declaring an inherited constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I'm having difficulties in defining a constructor for a class that inherits the properties of another class

```cpp
class Transportation {

public:
    int ID;
    string company;
    string vehicleOperator;

    Transportation(int,string,string) {
    }
};

class SeaTransport: public Transportation {

public:
    int portNumber;

    SeaTransport(int)::Transportation(int,string,string) {
    }
};
```

I'm having issues with line 18 (`SeaTransport(int)::Transportation(int,string,string)`).

The error I receive occurs at the pont where I declare `Transportation`.

As seen in the code, a class `Transportation` is the body class and class `SeaTransport` inherits the properies of `Transportation`.

```
Transportation::Transportation(int, std::string, std::string)
+2 overloads

type name is not allowed
```

This error occurs at the int

```
typedef std::__cxx11::basic_string std::string
type name is not allowed
```

and this final error occurs at both string variables.

Comment: The syntax you're using does not make much sense.
You simply need to declare a constructor in the derived class, and in the definition you need to make sure that you call the base class constructor, you will also need to provide actual values to the function call:
`SeaTransport(int input) : Transportation(input,"","") {}`

Comment: It is sufficient to provide the type of the arguments alone in the case of a function declaration. But when you are defining the function, you need to provide the variables where you will be storing the data.

Comment: FWIW (although possibly not strictly related): a `ret Class::method(..){..}`-style member definition needs to be _outside_ the class declaration; and usually in a non-header .cc file. For an in inline member definition, remove the `Class::` bit. This holds for constructors as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you mix together scoping and a constructor initializer list.

The double-colon operator `::` is for scope, while a constructor followed by a *single* colon and a list of initializations is an initializer list.

You must declare the `SeaTransport` constructor to take *all* the arguments, including those for the parent class (assuming you want to pass them on to the base constructor):

```
SeaTransport(int port, int id, string company, string operator);
```

Then in the definition (implementation) of the constructor you "call" the parent constructor in the constructor initializer list:

```
SeaTransport(int port, int id, string company, string oper)
   : Transport(id, company, oper), // "Call" the parent class constructor
     portNumber(port)  // Initialize the own members
{
}
```

Comment: You don't have to get any of the arguments in the derived class, you do have to provide the base class all of the arguments to the constructor.
For example you can just call it with `Transport(0,"","")`

Answer (score 0):

As Mr Some Programmer Dude said, you've a Scope problem in your code,
I will try to answer for your second question which is, how to add featured variables on your constructor.

Same as what you did for the `port` attribute.

You can define before all your Attribute which is `boatNumber` as `int boadNumber = 0` then, you'll overload your
 constructor with `boatNumber(num)` after the initializer operator and `int num` before the initializer operator.

```
class Transportation {

public:
    int ID;
    string company;
    string vehicleOperator;

    Transportation(int,string,string) {
    }
    ~Transportation(){}
};

class SeaTransport: public Transportation {

public:
    int portNumber;
    int boatNumber;

   SeaTransport(int num, int port, int id, string company, string oper)
   :Transportation(id, company, oper), boatNumber(num),portNumber(port)  {}

   ~SeaTransport(){}
};
```

But, if you want to get things more specific, you can create another class which is derived from `SeaTransport`
And then you'll define the number of your `boat` and more other details, if you want.

I'll draw you an instance of it :

```
 class Boat: public SeaTransport {

    public:

        int boatNumber;

        Boat(int bNum,int num, int port, int id, string company, string oper):
SeaTransport( num, port, id, company, oper),boatNumber(bNum){}

        ~Boat(){}
    };
```